# UIWebView webViewDidLoadFinish method not called

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift

I've been playing around with web views in swift this evening, but have run into a bit of an issue.

For some reason I'm not able to get the webViewDidStartLoad or webViewDidFinishLoad methods to fire.
In my storyboard, I have an outlet called webView linked to my UIWebView element.

Is anyone able to help me with what I am doing wrong?

This is my viewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView : UIWebView

    var url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //load initial URL
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL : url)
        webView.loadRequest(req)
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        println("AA")
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        println("BB")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set webView's delegate?

Comment: Yeah, just add `webview.delegate = self;` in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks heaps.It looks like I hadn't set the delegate for the webview.

As a newbie, it's not really made very clear that you have to do that in any of the tutorials I've been going through.

I did find this video helpful though:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFF1c-RgMkU

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this!

```
var req = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
webView.delegate = self
webView.loadRequest(req)
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue, even I did confirmed the UIWebViewDelete to self and implemented its methods.

```
//Document file url
var docUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjjwPSnoKfNAhXFRo8KHf6ACGYQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.snee.com%2Fxml%2Fxslt%2Fsample.doc&usg=AFQjCNGG4FxPqcT8RXiIRHcLTu0yYDErdQ&sig2=ejeAlBgIZG5B6W-tS1VrQA&bvm=bv.124272578,d.c2I&cad=rja")

let req = NSURLRequest(URL: docUrl!)
webView.delegate = self
//here is the sole part
webView.scalesPageToFit = true
webView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
webView.loadRequest(req)
```

above logic worked perfectly with test URl I got from quick google search.

But I when I replaced with mine. webViewDidFinishLoad never get called.

**then How we solved?**

On backed side we had to define **content-type as document** in headers. and it works like charm.

> So please make sure on your server back-end side as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my 2 cents battling with the same problem in ***SWIFT 3***:

```
class HintViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate
```

Declare the delegate methods this way (note the declaration of the arguments):

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
```

Remember to set self to the webview's delegate property either in **Interface Builder** (Select the webview, drag from the delegate outlet to the webview from the Connections Inspector OR **programmatically**: self.webview.delegate = self)

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, setting the delegate of `UIWebView` and conforming to the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol is the best possible solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

For other's who might make it here. I had put my delegate methods in a `private extension` which couldn't be accessed by the delegate caller. Once I changed the extension to `internal` the delegates started to get called properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is my detailed solution for Swift 3:

**1)** in class declaration write the **UIWebViewDelegate**. For example:

class MyViewController: UIViewController, **UIWebViewDelegate** {

**2)** of course in storyboard make link to your UIViewController like this:
**@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!**

**3)** in the func viewDidLoad add one line:
**self.webView.delegate = self**

Nothing more. Special thinks to LinusGeffarth and LLIAJLbHOu for idea.